# I have a large dataframe where some of the column have "?" .I am trying to count home "?" in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This code is only working for single column but i want to work with entire dataframe

```
passNum = []
for i in range (len(price)):
  if price[i] == '?':
    passNum.append(numberOfPassengers[i])
print(passNum)
```

Comment: is numberOfPassengers DataFrame?

Comment: Please make this a running script including a small example dataframe that we can use for test.

Comment: Lets clear the question, do you have column name like "?", or you have "?" for cells. Can you show the small example of data?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making the question a running script so we can help you better.

Any how, from the title what I understand is that you want to count the occurrence of a particular character in the dataframe.

You can try this.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"name":['a', 'b', '?', 'd'], "age":[1, 2, 3, "?"], "add":['a', '?', 's', '?']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

count = 0
find_character = "?"

for i in df:
    for j in df[i].to_list():
        if j == find_character:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

### **Explanation**

---

In the outer for loop

```py
for i in df:
```

we are extracting all the columns in in the dataframe one by one and storing it in variable `i`.

In the inner for loop

```py
for j in df[i].to_list():
```

First we extract the column stored in i from the dataframe and convert it into a list using `.to_list()` function. Then, we loop through each element in the list using for loop and check if it is `"?"` or not by using an if statement.

```py
if j == find_character:
```

If we find a match then we increment the value of variable `count` by one [`count += 1`]

At the end we print the `count` variable to get total number of `"?"` precent in dataframe.

There could be a better solution. I highly respect any suggestion.

---

### ***Suggestions in Comments***

As suggested by [@Lazyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8282898/lazyer) in the comments, the following is a simpler way to accomplish the task.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x=="?").sum().sum()
```

It is smaller and much simpler way to complete the task.

Comment: **df.applymap(lambda x: x=="?").sum().sum()** Here is one more solution in this case.

Comment: @Lazyer Can I use your comment in my answer?

Comment: Sure you can use :)